# How to add delay only when the function is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to call the function with delay.

```
       window.setInterval(function(){

        //$('.product-display').delay(3000).hide();
        document.getElementById('product-list-display').style.display = "none";

       },3000);
```

The above code hides the div after 3 seconds, the above snippet is called in show div function. what i need to do is, i want to invoke the the above delay function only when the show div function is called...right now the function executes every 3 secnds i.e i am using setInterval for hiding. but i want to hide after 3 seconds only when show div is called. how can i do this?
can i use jquery?

```
function showdiv(city, imagesrc, timeout)
{
   window.setTimeout(function() {

    document.getElementById('city-order').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('order-product').innerHTML = "";

    $('.product-display').addClass("zoomin");  

    document.getElementById('product-list-display').style.display = "block";

    var order_placed_city = document.getElementById('city-order');
    var content = document.createTextNode(city);
    order_placed_city.appendChild(content);

    var product_order = document.getElementById('order-product');
    var elem = document.createElement("img");
    product_order.appendChild(elem);

    elem.src = imagesrc;

  },timeout); 

   window.setTimeout(function(){
         //$('.product-display').delay(3000).hide();
         document.getElementById('product-list-display').style.display = "none";
   },3000);
}
```

Comment: You can call `setTimeout` anywhere you like, including within some other function. The above code you pasted should execute the `document.getElementById('product-list-display').style.display = "none";` code 3 seconds after shodiv is invoked. What exactly does not work?

Comment: I am sorry but the question is really not clear.. in showdiv you are using _setTimeout_ and in above snippet you using _setInterval_.. Plus the function called as _showdiv_ only hides the element_(#product-list-display)_ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the hide setTimeout  1 line up :

```
function showdiv(city, imagesrc, timeout)
{
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('city-order').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('order-product').innerHTML = "";
        $('.product-display').addClass("zoomin");  
        document.getElementById('product-list-display').style.display = "block";
        var order_placed_city = document.getElementById('city-order');
        var content = document.createTextNode(city);
        order_placed_city.appendChild(content);
        var product_order = document.getElementById('order-product');
        var elem = document.createElement("img");
        product_order.appendChild(elem);
        elem.src = imagesrc;

        window.setTimeout(function(){
            //$('.product-display').delay(3000).hide();
            document.getElementById('product-list-display').style.display = "none";
        },3000);

    },timeout); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using callback function to achieve this.

```
function showdiv(city, imagesrc, timeout)
{
  window.setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('city-order').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('order-product').innerHTML = "";
  $('.product-display').addClass("zoomin");  
  showDiv(function(){   window.setTimeout(function(){
    //$('.product-display').delay(3000).hide();
    document.getElementById('product-list-display').style.display = "none";
   },3000);});
  var order_placed_city = document.getElementById('city-order');
  var content = document.createTextNode(city);
  order_placed_city.appendChild(content);
  var product_order = document.getElementById('order-product');
  var elem = document.createElement("img");
  product_order.appendChild(elem);
  elem.src = imagesrc;
  },timeout); 
}

function showDiv(callback){
  document.getElementById('product-list-display').style.display = "block";
  callback();
}
```